# Is the category of modules over the localization ring an example of a localization of a category?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules, localization

Consider r to be a non-unit element of a ring R and S the subset of R consisting of its natural powers. Wikipedia states that the categorical localization of the category of modules over R with respect to family of morphisms defined by multiplication by elements of S is in fact the category of modules over the localization of the ring R with respect to S. Can anyone help me prove this, please?

I mean the example given in the 'Introduction and motivation' section here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_category

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.  For instance, take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $r=2$.  If the claimed statement were true, then the localization of categories that inverts all the maps $2:M\to M$ would have to turn the inclusion map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ into an isomorphism.  So, there would be an inverse map $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\to\mathbb{Z}$ in the localization that can be represented as a zigzag $$\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\to M_1\leftarrow M_2\to\dots\leftarrow M_n\to \mathbb{Z}$$ of maps of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules where all the backwards maps are of the form $2:M\to M$, such that when you tensor with $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ and replace the backwards maps with division by $2$, the composition just becomes the identity map $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\to\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$.  Now note that if we skip all the backwards maps in this zigzag and compose only the forwards maps (which is possible since the backwards maps all have the same domain and codomain), the resulting map $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\to\mathbb{Z}$ would have to send $1$ to $2^k$, where $k$ is the number of backwards maps in the zigzag.  But this is impossible, since there are no nonzero homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]\to\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So there is no connection between the  the categorical localization of the category of modules over R with respect to family of morphisms defined by multiplication by elements of S and the category of modules over the localization of the ring R with respect to S? It seemed like a natural example...

Comment: Well, the ring-theoretic localization factors through the categorical localization.  But the ring-theoretic localization does much more than just formally invert the maps $r:M\to M$ in a categorical sense.

Comment: I think the ring-theoretic localization can be described as a categorical localization that inverts the multiplication by $r$ maps when you restrict to cocomplete categories and functors that preserve colimits (or even just sequential colimits).  The idea is that preserving colimits would force the map $M\to M[1/r]$ to become an isomorphism in the localization since it can be constructed as a colimit of a sequence $M\to M\to M\to\dots$ where the maps are all multiplication by $r$.  I haven't checked the details of this though.

Comment: Yes, by virtue of the full and faithful inclusion $\mathrm{Mod}_{R[S^{-1}]} \to \mathrm{Mod}_R$ admitting a left adjoint, this is a (categorical) localization. However, it inverts everything in the *strong saturation* of the class of multiplication-by-elements-of-$S$.

Comment: You actually mean the restriction of scalars functor, right?

Comment: Ah, yes that's exactly what I mean. Actually, what I said originally is a bit off. What I should have said is "Yes, by virtue of the functor $R[S^{-1}]\otimes_R ({-}) : \mathrm{Mod}_R \to \mathrm{Mod}_{R[S^{-1}]}$ admitting a full and faithful right adjoint..."

Comment: yes, of course. thanks!

Comment: It is the Verdier quotient by the subcategory of $R$-modules on which the multiplication by $r$ is *locally* nilpotent, right?